# Are Dr. Zakir Naik's speeches banned in the UK, Canada, and Malaysia?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, censorship, malaysia

[NDTV](http://www.ndtv.com/mumbai-news/criminal-case-registered-against-controversial-preacher-zakir-naik-1643594), which is currently [India's Most Trusted TV Media Brand](http://www.ndtv.com/convergence/ndtv/corporatepage/index.aspx), claims:

> Mr Naik's speeches are banned in the UK, Canada and Malaysia.

[This post](http://www.thedailystar.net/frontpage/the-daily-star-protests-dr-naiks-claims-1251430) by *The Daily Star* (Bangladesh's most widely circulated English newspaper) says he is not banned in Malaysia:

> The Daily Star stands corrected on its report that he was banned in Malaysia.
>
> He also talked about his own ban in different countries.
>
> Naik in his speech said that three years ago he received one of the
>   most prestigious awards in Malaysia. He added that he was in Malaysia
>   hardly three months back and met several ministers there.

It further says:

> However, about his case in the UK, Naik himself said:  “The only
>   country that I am officially aware of ban, once from entering, was UK.
>   I don't have any proof that any country has banned me officially.”
>
> About the Canada issue, according to the top Canadian newspaper
>   Toronto Star, Zakir Naik in June 2010 was phoned by a Canadian embassy
>   official in New Delhi to say that he would be refused entry if he
>   decided to come. Naik was set to attend a conference in Canada at that
>   time.
>
> The report adds that “At the same time, nothing was put in writing”.
>
> The Daily Star's reporting was a mere presentation of facts and we
>   regret any misunderstanding between Dr Zakir Naik and this newspaper.

Are Dr. Zakir Naik's speeches banned in the UK, Canada, and Malaysia?

Comment: Relevant: http://web.archive.org/web/20160705172141/http://www.thedailystar.net/frontpage/2-attackers-followed-radical-preacher-recruiters-1250482

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: My guess is that the reason people downvote you is that your questions are focusing too much on a single personality and on claims which seem to be about specific wordings. This kind of claims is unlikely to be useful to many people in the future.

Comment: More in general, [this is when downvotes are appropriate](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Basically if you don't show research effort or post non-useful questions.

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for pointing that out. I added research effort. xD

Comment: Are you asking whether (a) he is banned from entering those countries, (b) able to enter but banned from giving speeches in person, in those counties or (c) there is a ban on the broadcasting, publication, dissemination or reporting of his speeches and the content of his speeches?

Answer (score 1):

His planned speech was banned in Malaysia, but he isn't currently banned.

According to [Zakir Naik back in Malaysia](http://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation/2016/10/24/zakir-naik-visit/) 24 October 2016 :

> Islamic scholar Dr Zakir Naik (pic) is back in Malaysia, having attended the annual conference of Al-Khadem in Kuala Lumpur on Sunday.
>
> The preacher also met Deputy Prime Minister Datuk Seri Dr Ahmad Zahid Hamidi at his home.

...

> This is Dr Zakir's second visit to the country this year.
>
> He was in Malaysia in April to give talks on Islam.
>
> Dr Zakir gave a series of lectures in Terengganu in April while his scheduled talk at Universiti Teknikal Malaysia Melaka, which **was earlier banned by police, was given the green light after a compromise was reached – that the theme of the talk is changed**.

In the UK, he was banned in June 2010 by Home Secretary Theresa May when she [said](http://www.bbc.com/news/10349564) :

> Numerous comments made by Dr Naik are evidence to me of his unacceptable behaviour.
>
> Coming to the UK is a privilege, not a right and I am not willing to allow those who might not be conducive to the public good to enter the UK.
>
> Exclusion powers are very serious and no decision is taken lightly or as a method of stopping open debate on issues

For Canada, see [Controversial Muslim televangelist Zakir Naik banned from Toronto conference](http://news.nationalpost.com/news/canada/controversial-muslim-televangelist-zakir-naik-banned-from-toronto-conference) National Post 22 June 2010 and [Canada tells Muslim speaker to stay home, imam says](https://www.thestar.com/news/gta/2010/06/22/canada_tells_muslim_speaker_to_stay_home_imam_says.html) form The Star 29 June 2010.

Comment: What about UK and Canada?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Ok, I added

Comment: How does that demonstrate that his speeches are banned in Canada and UK? The way I see it, Canada and UK doesn't like him, so they prevented him from giving speeches by blocking his entry to their respective countries but they didn't ban his speeches (that would be taken as an attack on "free speech").

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin He had scheduled speeches at conferences in the 3 countries, but wasn't allowed to come give the speeches. But Malaysian changed its decision after he agreed to change the speech.

Comment: He was prevented from entering those countries (that's not a official ban like the ban on Richard Spencer, the guy who hailed Trump with Nazi salutes). That's different from banning his speeches. None of them has officially banned him. There is a huge diff between someone not getting to enter a country and not being allowed to say what he wants in public.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Yes, it is a big difference.  He was just prevented from entering the countries, where he planned to make speeches.

Comment: But the claim clearly says his speeches are banned. "Mr Naik's speeches are banned in the UK, Canada and Malaysia." which implies that he is officially banned from giving speeches in those countries.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I think after reading my answer people will have the true information.

Comment: National post doesn't sound like a good source for true information.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin ok, I added another Canada reference